# SQL Server: How to find the result with 2 criteria: one equals certain column; the other doesn't equal another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a question as shown in pic: SKU is unique, its name can get different sizes.

I want to use SQL Server to display its other size (with same NAME).

How can I achieve it?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your output shows a single "other size", but in reality, wouldn't you have multiple other sizes? Large, Extra Large? How would you want to deal with that

Comment: @Tanner, indeed I could have maximely 3 sizes, some have 2 sizes and others could have 3 sizes. But if I could firstly display the other one size, it will be still quite useful.

Comment: any query that's written if multiple sizes exist will return multiple rows for the same item. If you want the query to display one size, how will you choose which one if multiple exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which will work well for three sizes.  The inner group by query matches a given size with the maximum (lexigraphically) other size.  The second join then attaches the third size.  In cases where there be only one or two sizes, the placeholder `NA` is used in the result set.

I have tested this query on SQL Server directly and it appears to be working, at least for the edge cases I tested.

```
SELECT t1.SKU,
       t1.NAME,
       t1.SIZE AS SIZE1,
       COALESCE(t1.OtherSize, 'NA') AS SIZE2,
       COALESCE(t2.SIZE, 'NA') AS SIZE3
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.SKU, t1.NAME, t1.SIZE, MAX(t2.SIZE) AS OtherSize
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.NAME = t2.NAME AND t1.SIZE <> t2.SIZE
    GROUP BY t1.SKU, t1.NAME, t1.SIZE        
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.NAME = t2.NAME AND
       t2.SIZE <> t1.SIZE AND
       t2.SIZE <> t1.OtherSize
```

Here is the output I got:

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your prompt answer. What if I got maximely 3 sizes, some have 2, and some have 3?

Comment: @Héléna You need to answer Tanner's question, namely what logic do you want to use in such a case?  It's too bad that SQL Server has no built in `GROUP_CONCAT` function, which would work wonders for your problem.

Comment: @Héléna this is why you should clarify your question, so people don't post answers that won't help you with the full problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen，sorry initially I simplify the questions. The final result I want to achieve is as newly uploaded pic. I hope it will display the 3 rows showing the sizes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it works~!! I am just curious what if I want to display the 3 columns cuz there are altogether 3 sizes for some "NAME"?

Comment: @Héléna I have updated my answer, which now has three size columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks a lot, let me try it and then give you feedback~~

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, really thanks a lot, I have tested it, it works like a charm~~~

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic query

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Tbl', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tbl;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempTpl', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTpl;

CREATE TABLE #Tbl (SKU NVARCHAR(50), Name NVARCHAR(50), Size NVARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO #Tbl
VALUES ('DRESS-M', 'DRESS', 'M'  ),
       ('DRESS-S', 'DRESS', 'S'  ),
       ('BLOUSE-L', 'BLOUSE', 'L'),
       ('BLOUSE-XL', 'BLOUSE', 'XL'),
       ('BLOUSE-S', 'BLOUSE', 'S'),
       ('SKIRT-S', 'SKIRT', 'S'  ),
       ('SKIRT-M', 'SKIRT', 'M'  ),
       ('SKIRT-L', 'SKIRT', 'L'  ),
       ('SKIRT-XL', 'SKIRT', 'XL'),
       ('SKIRT-XS', 'SKIRT', 'XS'),
       ('SKIRT-XS', 'SKIRT', 'XXL')

CREATE TABLE #TempTpl (SKU NVARCHAR(50), Name NVARCHAR(50), Size NVARCHAR(5), RowNumber INT)
INSERT INTO #TempTpl
SELECT 
    SKU,
    Name,
    Size,       
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Size) AS RowNumber
FROM 
    #Tbl    

DECLARE @Sizes TABLE (Size NVARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @Sizes
SELECT DISTINCT Size FROM #Tbl
WHERE
    Name = (                
                SELECT TOP 1
                    A.Name
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT Name, COUNT(1) AS CountOfSize FROM #Tbl
                    GROUP BY Name
                ) A
                ORDER BY A.CountOfSize DESC
            )

DECLARE @TmpSelect NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 
     @TmpSelect = COALESCE(@TmpSelect + ', ','') + '(SELECT TOP 1 Size FROM #TempTpl AS IT WHERE IT.Name = T.Name AND IT.RowNumber <> T.RowNumber AND IT.RowNumber = ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR(5)) +') AS Size' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR(5))
FROM @Sizes


DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query ='
            SELECT
                T.SKU,
                T.Name, 
                T.Size,' +
                    @TmpSelect          
                +'
            FROM
                #TempTpl T
            ORDER BY 
                T.Name,
                Size'
--SELECT @Query
EXEC  sp_executesql @Query
```

Output

```
SKU             Name        Size  Size1 Size2 Size3 Size4 Size5 Size6
--------------- ----------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
BLOUSE-L        BLOUSE      L     NULL  S     XL    NULL  NULL  NULL
BLOUSE-S        BLOUSE      S     L     NULL  XL    NULL  NULL  NULL
BLOUSE-XL       BLOUSE      XL    L     S     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
DRESS-M         DRESS       M     NULL  S     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
DRESS-S         DRESS       S     M     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
SKIRT-L         SKIRT       L     NULL  M     S     XL    XS    XXL
SKIRT-M         SKIRT       M     L     NULL  S     XL    XS    XXL
SKIRT-S         SKIRT       S     L     M     NULL  XL    XS    XXL
SKIRT-XL        SKIRT       XL    L     M     S     NULL  XS    XXL
SKIRT-XS        SKIRT       XS    L     M     S     XL    NULL  XXL
SKIRT-XXL       SKIRT       XXL   L     M     S     XL    XS    NULL
```